# PHP Class - Call array variable

Tags: php, class, variables

I am stuck part of this code.. I tried to call my static table variables but I can't.

Methinks I have very simple problem but.. effective and harmful for my project.

my class:

```
<?php

public $table;

class Functions
{
    public function ehe()
    {
        return $table[4];
    }
}

?>
```

my system.php file:

```
    $fn = new Functions();

    /* static tables */
    $table  = array(
                    0 => 'account.account',
                    1 => 'player.player',
                    2 => 'auction_house.items',
                    3 => 'auction_house.admin',
                    4 => 'auction_house.store',
                    5 => 'auction_house.styles',
                    6 => 'auction_house.logs',
                    7 => 'auction_house.coupons',
                    );
```

my index file(example): (connected with system.php & classes)

```
echo $fn->ehe;
```

my error:

```
Notice: Undefined property: Functions::$ehe in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\.......php on line 178
```

**A Little second question:
Also I have 2 classes.
1: Functions class. (Include query processings etc.)
2: MySQL connect class.
I want to connect this two classes for queries. How is this possible? ..**

Comment: Well $table is out of scope in the ehe() method

Comment: `$table` is out of scope, as Mark said. Also you're accesing a property here `echo $fn->ehe` which is a variable inside that class. You have to call `echo $fn->ehe()` in order to access a method. Methods and functions **always** have to be called with their parentheses, even if they don't receive parameters (well, not "always"... there are exceptions like `echo`, to mention one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You're accessing `ehe` as if it were a property rather than a method. Method calls always have `()`, which contain arguments if necessary.
- You can't modify the visibility of variables in the global scope - your `public $table;` will cause a syntax error.
- `$table` is out of scope in your `ehe()` method.

You could potentially use the `global` keyword:

```
$table;

class Functions {
    public function ehe() {
        global $table;
        return $table[4];
    }
}

$fn = new Functions();

/* static tables */
$table = array(
            0 => 'account.account',
            1 => 'player.player',
            2 => 'auction_house.items',
            3 => 'auction_house.admin',
            4 => 'auction_house.store',
            5 => 'auction_house.styles',
            6 => 'auction_house.logs',
            7 => 'auction_house.coupons',
        );

echo $fn->ehe(); // auction_house.store
```

Comment: Yes that's it.
But I am using this table variables from system.php, system.php is a static file for another functions (without classes.)
So here, I am trying to use this variables for both.
Function class & other functions..
I hope you understand me.

Comment: @AlihanPehlivan look at the `return` language constructor documentation. It says that you could use `return` in a script used by `include()` to actually return something to another script. I was wondering if you could include something inside your class ;)

Comment: still system.php & another classes connected(included)
I had another problem but now solved @AlejandroIván also I was using global keyword for my old functions, I did not know working for classes :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call it, it's a function, not a property.

```
echo $fn->ehe();
```

Comment: I did it, I have imminent problem again

**Notice: Undefined variable: table in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\... on line 178**